# Cannot open file (No file received) - while opening a pdf file through Intent ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

While opening a pdf file through Intent ACTION_VIEW I am getting this message and the pdf viewer app closes after showing the message. This behavior is observed in all version of Android. I am surprised that the same file is being shared and it works. Also, I am able to view another file type with the similar FileProvider. Please let me know if you have any solution.

```
 Intent intentShowPDF = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (directory != null) {

        // So you have to use Provider
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "in.everybill.business.fileprovider", directory);
        intentShowPDF.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf");
        intentShowPDF.setType("application/pdf");
        intentShowPDF.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intentShowPDF.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intentShowPDF.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try {
                 activity.startActivity(intentShowPDF);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer");
              Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);

                staticContext.startActivity(intent);
            }

    } else {
        showToast("Failed");
    }
```

The manifest file

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="in.everybill.business.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: Please note, you have to set the android:exported="true" for the contentprovider of your application to be accessible to others.                       I wrote a small content on using the content provider to share/provide the access to the app private files. Please refer this link : http://androidwithashray.blogspot.in/2016/01/opening-sandbox-file-in-external-apps.html?view=flipcard

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the same FileProvider I am able to share the pdf file to other apps such as gmail, whatsapp. But I am unable to do so for pdf viewing. What could cause this? Is sharing and viewing the same file is different ?